# Типы компоновок

Tags: c++

Какие сущности относятся к внешней компоновки, какие к внутренней, а какие не имеют компоновки вовсе. Во всех учебниках эта тема слишком растянута, а на сайте [microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0yw6at8e.aspx) не понятно. Хотелось бы что бы было кратко и понятно.

Comment: extern  внешняя,   #include внутренная, если очень коротко...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Из стандарта Cpp11 3.5/2

> - When a name has external linkage , the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from scopes of
>     other translation units or from other scopes of the same translation unit.
> - When a name has internal linkage , the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from other scopes
>     in the same translation unit.
> - When a name has no linkage , the entity it denotes cannot be referred to by names from other scopes.

### Вольный перевод:

- Имя сущность, на которую можно сослаться по оному из другой единицы трансляции, имеет *внешнее связывание*.
- Имя сущность, на которую можно сослаться по оному из другой области видимости из той же единицы трансляции, имеет *внутреннее связывание*.
- Имя сущности, на которую нельзя сослаться по оному из другой области видимости, *не имеет связывания*.

### Примеры

Список не полный, если присмотреться, то несколько противоречивый, см. раздел 3.5 стандарта, если интересуют строгие определения.

Внешнее связывание:

- Глобальные функции и переменные **без** спецификатора `static`.
- Именованные `namespase`'ы и их члены, если они не подпадают под другие правила.
- Именованные структуры, классы и перечисления.
- Шаблоны.

Внутреннее связывание:

- Глобальные функции и переменные **со** спецификатором `static`. (основной способ указания, что идентификатор имеет внутреннее связывание, унаследован от Си).
- Константы `const` и `constexpr` без `extern`
- Безымянные `namespase`'ы и их члены.

Не имеет связывания:

- Всё, что объявлено в области видимости блоков без спецификатора `extern`, включая локальные переменные, типы и функции.
- Безымянные структуры, классы и перечисления без typedef'ов.
- Члены таких классов и перечислений.

### О терминологии:

Как настоял @BwanaTheMaster, термин «linkage», в данном контексте в литературе по С/С++ принято переводить как «связывание». Это отчасти отделяет его от близких терминов «linker» («компоновщик», изредка «редактор связей») и «компоновка» (процесс выполняемый компоновщиков при сборке исполняемого файла или библиотеки из объектных файлов), но с другой стороны этот термин более распространён в данном контексте и лучше отражает суть происходящего. В разговорной речи оба этих термины до определённой степени равнозначны заимствованному «линковка».

Comment: по ходу нужно разум делать более абстрактным, конкретика и связь с железом тока путают

Comment: Наверное смысл, вкладываемый в термин `linkage` в С++ иной, нежели приписывание определенных флагов к имени в таблице символов, которой пользуется ld, создавая исполняемый (или .so) модуль?

Comment: @avp, От Cи ключевое отличается в том, что плюсы распространяют эти понятие на типы... в остальном в наивной реализации (на `-O0`) всё точно также: для внутренней линковки символы попадают в объектник с определёнными флагами, а в реальном варианте (как и для Си) компилятор имеет право всё это встроить и не объявлять символы вовсе...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а каков же механизм внешней линковки для, скажем, структур? Т.е. как линкер сможет проверить тип внешнего символа? Или имеется в виду mangling (кажется так называют добавление магических символов, зависящих от типа, к имени переменной (внешнего объекта))? (опять что-то нотификация о комментариях хандрит. Задержка -- час)

Comment: @avp, честно скажу, так глубоко не разбираюсь, но на сколько я понимаю разделение внутренней и внешней линковки для типов вводится на уровне языка чтобы корректно обрабатывать линковку функций-членов, статических членов и виртуальных таблиц (они точно при компиляции выделяются как отдельные символы)... Не думаю, что для простых типов какое-то символы попадают в объектник...

Comment: Слово "linkage" в данном контексте издревле переводится, как "связывание".

Comment: @BwanaTheMaster не совсем так, о «связывании» говорят при подключении внешних библиотек (статических или динамических), а при описании сборки бинарника (исполняемого или библиотеки) из объектных файлов обычно пользуются термином «компоновка».

Comment: С чего Вы взяли? Слово "linkage" отностится к типам символов в единицах трансляции, из которых транслятор делает объектный модуль. Есть локальные, глобальные (экспортируемые) и внешние (импортируемые). Других нет. Все это описано в руководствах по форматам объектных модулей и языкам ассемблера. Когда именно выполняется связывание, в процессе компоновки или после загрузки, не имеет отношения к "linkage type".

Слово "linkage" переводится как "связывание" с тех самых времен, как эти самые объектные модули появились. Это времена IBM360/370, а то и раньше. С тех пор сама технология не изменилась

Comment: @BwanaTheMaster, честно сказать, никогда не видел строгих определений этих терминов (связывание и компоновка) на русском (буду полностью убеждён, если сошлёшься на какого-нибудь автора/переводчика, которому можно доверять)... В своё время ЕМНИП встречал их вперемешку и разделил их именно так, а для себя дабы не путаться в этом бардаке использовал варваризмы... но вся литература, к которой есть быстрый доступ сейчас говорит, что я не прав (полумашинные переводы из MSDN'а в расчёт не беру)... в любом случае этого достаточно, чтобы добавить приписку в ответ для поисковика...

Comment: Практически все переводчики книг издательств "Финансы и статистика" и "Радио и связь". Плюс, постоянно выпускались терминологические словари. 
Многие серьезные переводные книги имели отдельный раздел с терминологией.

Comment: Забыл, еще и издательство "Мир".
Словарь (один из многих) 
http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=EF8A9F4CF3140F84A69E199734CEF0E8